# Which is a better intermediate micro textbook: Perloff (with calculus) or baby Varian (with calculus)?

Tags: microeconomics

I’m currently learning intermediate microeconomics *with calculus.* I know to take derivatives, partial derivatives, integrals, and multiple integrals, and I know some basic linear algebra (solving systems of linear equations using Cramer’s rule or inverse matrices, dot and cross products of vectors, gradients of vector functions). I also know some constrained optimization, through substitution and Lagrangian methods (including SOCs), though not Kuhn-Tucker conditions.

Given this background, I’m deciding between two books. One is *Microeconomics: Theory and Applications with Calculus* by Jeffrey Perloff (*not* to be confused with his other textbook, *Microeconomics*) and the other is *Intermediate Microeconomics with Calculus* by Hal Varian (*not* to be confused with his two other textbooks, *Intermediate Microeconomics* and *Microeconomic Analysis*). Which is better and why?

In particular, my trade-off is: Perloff has a lot of practice problems, including solved exercises, and it seems like solving lots of problems is a good way to learn micro. Varian doesn’t have nearly as many – his book of problems, *Workouts in Intermediate Microeconomics*, has barely any calculus. Perloff also has more examples/applications. In contrast, Varian has two main benefits. First, it has more material on mechanism design, which is interesting. Second, I’ve heard it is a good precursor to Varian’s more advanced textbook, *Microeconomic Analysis.*

I’m leaning toward Perloff at the moment – I have already started working through it – but would appreciate thoughts.

Comment: Seems opinion based but I'm a huge hal varian fan. this is because he walks students directly from introductory micro to intermediate and advanced topics with great writing and gets to the point.